# Call method based on type

Tags: c#, interface

I have combined two types (Type1 and Type2) into one list, by creating an interface they both inherit from.

```
List<IMyinterface> allElementsList = new List<IMyinterface>();
```

I now would like to loop through allElementsList, and depending on the Type (Type1 or Type2), do something.

I have set up my code like this:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class Type1 : IMyinterface
{
    void DoSomething();
}    
public class Type2 : IMyinterface
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

I thought I could just do something like this, and it would call the correct DoSomthing() method depending on the type.

```
foreach(var i in allElementsList)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

The above loop is not calling the correct method. How can I call the correct method based on type?

Comment: `i.DoSomething()`?

Comment: As a side note "*But this is not working*" is **not** a problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach(var i in allElementsList)
{
    i.DoSomething();
}
```